# Zero function test for whether or not a subset is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My linear algebra professor keeps on emphasizing that we do a zero test before we check for closure under addition and multiplication, when we check whether a subset is a subspace. I understand how to perform the zero test when we have a vector, but I'm not sure how to go about it when the subset is defined as a function. For example
$$ V =
\left\{f : \mathbb R → \mathbb R \mid f(x) = (c_1x+c_2)/
[(x−1)(x−2)],\ c_1, c_2 ∈ \mathbb R\right\} $$
How would I do a 0 function test on this?

Comment: This is beside the point of the spirit of this question, but the zero element of $V$ (namely, the zero function $x \mapsto 0$) isn't in $V$ for the technical reason that $V$ is empty---none of the functions $f$ defined are defined at $1$ or $2$ and so none are functions $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

In this vector space, the vectors (members of the vector space) are functions. So, the zero vector is the zero function i.e. $f(x)=0 \; \forall x$. So check that this function is in the subspace.